# Codename One Date gives different results on iOS and Android

Tags: ios, date, datetime, codenameone

I need to get the current time as HH:mm. So I wrote this method to get hours and minutes from the current date :

```
    final public static String[] getArrayOfCurrentTime(){

    Dialog.show("", "La date est " + (new Date()).toString(), "OK", null);  
    // Android : La date est Thu Jul 07 17:00:34 CEST 2016
    // iOS : La date est 7 Juillet 2016

    String time = Util.split( (new Date()).toString(), " ")[3];
    String hour = Util.split( time, ":")[0];
    String  min = Util.split( time, ":")[1];
    String sec = Util.split( time, ":")[2];

    return new String []{hour, min, sec};
}
```

It appears that Android gives a Datetime whereas iOS gives a Date.

Consequently on iOS I get and Array Index out of bounds. I can't find anything in the documentation about a difference in behaviour between iOS and Android regarding Date. Do I have to compute my result from milli seconds since epoch, or I have missed something?

Comment: I know exactly nothing about Codename One. I don't even know what it is. However, I know a LOT about iOS development. In iOS, if you simply use a date's string property, you get a date and time string in a fixed format, in UTC. If you want a date or time string in a specific format, you should probably use an `NSDateFormatter` object.  Since I don't know anything about Codename One, I have no idea how you'd go about that, but it should help you search at least.

Comment: Thanks Duncan C. However I try as much as possible to avoid using native code (see Codename one motto is Write Once [in java] Run Everywhere)!

Answer (score 1):

Use the SimpleDateFormat (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/l10n/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse Dates

Comment: Thanks Chen! I don't have time yet to test it, but if Date() only outputs the date (DD MM YYYY) when running on iOS, there won't be any time (HH:mm) to parse on that platform, will there ?

Comment: Date includes everything, relying on `toString()` behavior is flaky. Personally I would use L10NManager to format the date.

Comment: Thanks @Shai . `l10n.formatDateTime(new Date()))` seems the way to go indeed according to [CN1 documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/l10n/L10NManager.html). Much simpler than my answer below! I will try it asap and change the accepted answer if it does work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep it portable (iOS and Android) and to avoid writing native code I made the computation myself only with Codename One methods as shown below  :

```
final public static String[] getArrayOfCurrentTime(){
    Calendar cal = new Calendar(); // current Date and time
    long today = cal.getCurrentDate().getTime(); // only the date
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // only time
    long minutesInDay = (now - today) / (60 * 1000); // number of minutes between midnight and now

    int nowHours = (int) (minutesInDay / 60);
    int nowMinutes = (int) ((minutesInDay / 60) % 60); 

    Dialog.show("", "L'heure est " + nowHours + ":" + nowMinutes, "OK", null); 
// (Android and iOS) L'heure est 18:10

    return new String []{Integer.toString(nowHours), Integer.toString(nowMinutes)};
}
```